# Having Difficulties displaying Xamarin Views

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

Hey I am trying to create a really basic android app to talk to a server programmatically but when I run the apk on my phone, the app is blank. Any help would be appreciated.

I was having issues with xaml so I removed it when I found out that it can be done in c#.

I think the issue might be the lack of a view but I am not really sure how to do that and I couldnt find anything online.

I want the app to have a text field to enter the ip addresses for my server and a button and slider to send codes back and forth.

I dont really care how it looks as long as it works because its a hobby project that only I will see it.

```
using System;
using Android.App;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Support.Design.Widget;
using Android.Support.V7.App;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using Xamarin.Essentials;
using Xamarin.Android;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;

namespace Lights
{
    [Activity(Label = "Lights", Icon = "@mipmap/ic_launcher_round", Theme = "@style/MainTheme", MainLauncher = true)]
    public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity
    {
        public IPAddress ip;
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
            Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
            var MyEditor = new Editor { Text = "IPADDRESS" };
            MyEditor.Completed += (sender,  e) => {
                bool ValidateIP = IPAddress.TryParse(MyEditor.Text, out ip);
                if (!ValidateIP) {
                    Toast.MakeText(this, "Invalid Ip Address", ToastLength.Short).Show();
                }
                
            };
            Slider slider = new Slider
            {
                Maximum = 20
            };
            Xamarin.Forms.Button button = new Xamarin.Forms.Button
            {
                Text = "POWER",
                VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand,
                HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center
            };
            button.Clicked += (sender, args) => sendMsg('1');
            slider.ValueChanged += (sender, args) =>
            {
                int value = (int)args.NewValue;
                sendMsg((char)('a' + value));
            };
            button.TextColor = Xamarin.Forms.Color.Red;
        }

        public void sendMsg(char a)
        {
             //this part works so i removed it for simplicity
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You didn't add them to the view heirarchy anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure if it is the `Xamarin.Forms` project or the `Xamarin.Android` project.

If it's a Xamarin.Android project,it's better to create a xml with the native control(not the element in your codes above) to display your layout,you could refer to [Xamarin Android](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/get-started/hello-android/hello-android-quickstart?pivots=windows#create-a-layout).

If it's a Forms project,you should create a page in the forms project and add the above codes in your page.cs.You could refer to [Xamarin Forms](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/get-started/quickstarts/single-page?pivots=win-vs2017).